# How to load http videos over https site?

Tags: iframe

```
<iframe width="420" height="345"  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/cH6kxtzovew">
</iframe>
```

When i am trying to load above youtube video in iframe over http site it is running successfully but when we load same iframe over https site it shows error such as

[blocked] The page at 'https://www.google.co.in/_/chrome/newtab?espv=2&ie=UTF-8' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/cH6kxtzovew': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Please give some idea to solve this problem thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the url source in your iframe to load the video via https:

`<iframe width="420" height="345"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cH6kxtzovew">
</iframe>`